# text annotations on different ggplot facets with labels from a dataframe from a list-column?

Tags: r, ggplot2, tidyr, geom-text, unnest

I have a nested tibble/dataframe that looks like this toy dataset

**(EDITED SINCE ORIGINAL POSTING)**:

```
library(tibble)
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(purrr)

id   <- c(1,2)
set.seed(123)
sess <- c(0,0,1,1,1,2,3,3,3,3,4,5,5,5,5,6)
meas <- c(rnorm(16, mean=3, sd=2))
meas2 <- c(rnorm(16, mean=2, sd=1))

test.tb <- tibble(id=id, 
                  sess=list(sess), 
                  spd=c(list(meas), list(meas2)))

test2.tb <- test.tb %>% mutate( 
                max  = unlist(map(spd, ~ round(max(., na.rm=TRUE),2))),
                mean = map2(sess, spd, calcXrun, mean))
```

Where I've clunkily defined by function `calcXrun` (suggestions to improve this very welcome!):

```
calcXrun <- function(sessVec, otherVec, FUN=max) {
  df <- data.frame(sess=sessVec,meas=otherVec)

  ## remove run 0
  df <- df[df$sess!=0,]
  calckedXrun <- aggregate(meas~sess, df, FUN, 
                           na.rm=TRUE, na.action="na.pass")
  calckedXrun$meas <- round(calckedXrun$meas,2)
  names(calckedXrun)[names(calckedXrun) == "meas"] <-         
             deparse(substitute(FUN))
  return(calckedXrun)
}
```

This gives me a tibble that looks like this:

```
> test2.tb
# A tibble: 2 x 5
    id sess       spd          max mean            
  <dbl> <list>     <list>     <dbl> <list>          
1     1 <dbl [16]> <dbl [16]>  6.57 <df[,2] [6 × 2]>
2     2 <dbl [16]> <dbl [16]>  3.25 <df[,2] [6 × 2]>
```

where my `mean` column, unnested, is

```
> test2.tb$mean
[[1]]
sess mean
1    1 4.17
2    2 6.43
3    3 2.03
4    4 5.45
5    5 3.16
6    6 6.57

[[2]]
sess mean
1    1 1.72
2    2 1.78
3    3 0.98
4    4 2.84
5    5 2.17
6    6 1.709
```

I would like to print out the dataframe nested in column `mean` of my tibble in the appropriate facet panel in ggplot, and I have a clunky way of doing it that I'd like to improve:

```
meanspd <- test2.tb %>% unnest(id,mean)
test2.tb %>% unnest(c(sess,spd)) %>% filter(sess > 0) %>% 
        ggplot() +
        geom_freqpoly(aes(x=spd, 
                   group=factor(sess), 
                   color=factor(sess)),
                   alpha=0.8) +
        scale_color_brewer(palette="Spectral") +
        theme_bw() +
        labs(color="run") +
        facet_grid(~ id) +
        geom_text(x=5, y=2,  inherit.aes=FALSE,
                  aes(label=paste("max spd",max)),
                  show.legend = FALSE) +
        geom_text(data=meanspd,  inherit.aes=FALSE,
                   aes(label=paste("sess",sess1, " mean ",mean), 
                       x=5, y=1.7-0.1*sess1),
                   show.legend = FALSE)
```

I also see that the geom_text of the non-list-column `max` gets overplotted (I assume as many times as I have `sess` levels). I feel like I would like to have access to the levels of `sess` so I can access specific rows in my nested dataframe and/or limit geom_text to printing `max` only once?

ggplot results:

[image: ggplot results]

Thanks in advance for any help/advice!

gj

Comment: Just a note -- I edited my original toy example so different id's have different data and amended my ggplot with another attempt that was independent of other forum members' suggestions that got me one step closer to what I was trying to go for.

Comment: ok i understand better now what the problem is not. You want the text/label to look like you're example, right? Just a better way of coding it? And you assume because the top line looks very bold, that it's being written many times? Everything else on the plot is okay?

Comment: Yeah, exactly. I was thinking I must be going about data "bookkeeping" the wrong way, i.e. how I'm storing/nesting the data could be better to facilitate data access for further calculations and plotting?

Comment: I'm getting an error now when I run your edited code, in the ggplot: Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) : object 'sess1' not found.

Comment: Oops, sorry -- the `data` for the `geom_text()` should be referencing `meanspd`, not `test2.tb`. I have corrected this in my original post.

Comment: i'm gettting a different error now, here: meanspd <- test2.tb %>% unnest(id,mean). 'Error: All nested columns must have the same number of elements'

Answer (score 0):

Your ggplot is fine. The issue is that `max` isn't calculated by `id`. Not sure exactly you go with the nested/list method (I found it difficult to understand the purpose of the function).

I replaced the beginning of the dplyr chain that you feed into ggplot with this, and then use the exact same ggplot on `dat`. This shows that `geom_text` is reading `max` by facet.

```
dat<- test.tb %>% unnest(c(sess,spd)) %>% filter(sess > 0) %>%
  mutate(max = if_else(id == 1, "Facet 1", "Facet 2"))
```

[image]

Comment: The function is supposed to group together the values in test.tb$spd by the values in test.tb$sess. 

Each facet corresponds to an id, though...So my real data has way more than just 2 facets/id's -- what would be a more general solution than hard-coding what should be in each facet? It seems like geom_text is looping through each level in the grouping factor `sess` and printing the same value each time because it's only an atomic value. Ideally, I would like to also get geom_text to print the values in test.tb$mean, where the first column is the same as the ggplot grouping factor `sess`.

Comment: I’m telling u it works as is. I only hardcoded for demonstration purpose. You need to do the summarizing differently. Use dplyr: group_by and summarise, no need for the function if I understand your goal correctly.

Comment: Chris: Of course I tried your suggestion before re-asking. As a newbie to tidyr/purrr/dplyr, I obviously am not thinking along those terms correctly yet -- so I would appreciate you spelling it out rather than assuming that I was being presumptuous. I can live with the `max` grouped by both `id` and `sess` like `mean` -- so one of my many failed attempts ff your advice:
`
    test3.tb <- test.tb %>% 
        unnest(c(sess)) %>% 
        group_by(id,sess) %>% 
        mutate(
          max   = unlist(map(spd, ~ round(max(., na.rm=TRUE),2))),
          mean = map(spd,mean))
`

Comment: For the ggplot, my prob was not it printing the wrong value per facet/`id` which you seemed to have understood as my problem -- ggplot was actually printing the correct values (I have edited my tox example to make this clearer). My prob was that it was also looping thru the grouping factor of `sess` and thus printing the correct values as many times as I had levels of max -- so it's not that the plot is wrong, I just want to do things properly to have a better grasp of this way of data wranging. Thx.

Comment: Gotcha - commenting back up on the question now.